# Specific Heat, Pore Fluid In ABAQUS

Tags: finite-element-method, solid-mechanics, plastic, abaqus

I want to model a problem that the theory behind is in the "Coupled Pore Fluid Flow and Stress Analysis" context that there is in the ABAQUS online documentation, version 2022. The link to the documentation is this [ [Coupled Pore Fluid Flow and Stress Analysis](https://help.3ds.com/2022/english/dssimulia_established/simacaebmkrefmap/simabmk-m-coupledporefluidflowandstressanalysis-sb.htm?contextscope=all&highlight=Coupled%20Pore%20Fluid%20Flow%20and%20Stress%20Analysis&id=264007b8e02f4f5fb26bc78a750c8102&analyticsContext=search-result&analyticsSearch=Coupled%20Pore%20Fluid%20Flow%20and%20Stress%20Analysis&myapp=false) ].

As you can see in the doc in the input file template it is mentioned that:

```
*SPECIFIC HEAT, PORE FLUID
Data lines to define specific heat of the permeating fluid if transient heat
```

As you can see, specific heat is defined for the pore fluid. How could I define the specific heat for the pore fluid in ABAQUS **CAE**? Because there isn't any module or anything like that for defining the specific heat of the pore fluid in the **Property Module** of the ABAQUS **CAE**.

Comment: the link requires a login